# Reference request: neocortex creating 11 dimensional structures

Tags: neuroscience, brain

I've come across several pop science articles [like this one](http://newatlas.com/brain-learn-11-dimensions/50100/) that vaguely describe a method of analyzing brain tissue involving algebraic topology and 11 dimensional structures. They all seem to cite each other. One of the researchers involved was Kathryn Hess. I've searched the web, a community college library, and the UCLA library and haven't been able to find the original paper. Does anyone know where I could learn more about their methods?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! You say `They all seem to cite each other`. It would help if you could directly tell us what papers you found and eventually why it feels like they all just cite each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New Frontiers is surrounded by controversy mostly becasue they have no restrictions about what they publish regardless of methodology or ethics. They also fired a bunch of their editors for trying to impose some scientific integrity. The fact the "journal" is owned by the first authors to publish in it is another bad sign. You can safely assume anything published by Frontiers is garbage.

Comment: That's a shame I thought the mathematical model that the researchers developed was really cool. I didn't pay much attention to their methods though.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found [the work.](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fncom.2017.00048/full) It was in the sources of the sources of the article that I gave as an example.

Comment: you should edit your question not answer it, especially just to add and not answer.